# Slick.js wrong arrows behaviour, how to solve?

Tags: javascript, jquery, slick.js

I'm using slick.js to create a carousel on my site. It must contain 4 element in a "no-infinite" scroll, the js i use is :

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('.caroselloslick').slick({
        lazyLoad: 'ondemand',
        infinite: false,
         slidesToShow: 4,
        slidesToScroll: 1
    });

});
```

Thre carousel works until the last element, here the slick carousel arrow becomes grey to indicate that i can't scroll anymore. Anyway if i click on the grey arrow , for example 3 times the number is registered by the plugin in some way... So if i wanna scroll back with the opposite arrow i have to click 3 times before the scroll begins... How i can do to block this behaviour?

Comment: Would you show all the options you have for the carousel? here is working with your options http://jsfiddle.net/q1qznouw/417/

Comment: all my options are in question, anything else my code

Comment: @user31929 I've added a solution to your issue. If you have any questions, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the slick events are firing despite the seemingly disabled state. You can query this using `console.log` to print a diagnostic message in the `afterChange` event:

```
$('.caroselloslick').on('afterChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide) {
  console.log('fired');
});
```

If you explicitly set the `disabled` attribute on the arrow buttons, this event will not fire on a click, thus ensuring that the slick counter is not updated, contrary to the actual state of the slick content.

Using the above information, you can introduce a helper method to set the `disabled` attribute of the arrow buttons dependant on the value of `aria-disabled`:

```
function checkArrowState($arrow) {
  if ($arrow.attr('aria-disabled') == 'true') {
    $arrow.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
  } else {
    $arrow.removeAttr('disabled');
  }
}
```

In the `afterChange` event, you can call the above method like so:

```
$('.caroselloslick').on('afterChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide) {
  checkArrowState($('.slick-arrow:eq(0)')); //Previous arrow
  checkArrowState($('.slick-arrow:eq(1)')); //Next arrow
});
```

The above can be improved further by checking which arrow button initiated the change, which I'll leave to you.

Please see the demo below for a working example:

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/yassarikhan786/faLpjd9d/)**